# Terraform Resource: aws_iam_instance_profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I reference the code at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_instance_profile, I created iam.tf file. I tried to attach the policy to an ec2 instance. I got an error:

```
aws_iam_role.role: Creating...
Error: failed creating IAM Role (jenkins_server_role): MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource
status code: 400, request id: c2b8db57-357f-4657-a692-a3e6026a6b7b

with aws_iam_role.role,
on iam.tf line 6, in resource "aws_iam_role" "role":
6: resource "aws_iam_role" "role" Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
ERRO[0011] Terraform invocation failed in /home/pluo/works/infra/jenkins
ERRO[0011] 1 error occurred:
        * exit status 1
```

Here is the iam.tf:

```
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "jenkins_server" {
  name = "jenkins_server"
  role = aws_iam_role.role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
  name = "jenkins_server_role"
  path = "/"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "elasticloadbalancing:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cloudwatch:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "autoscaling:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": [
                        "autoscaling.amazonaws.com",
                        "ec2scheduled.amazonaws.com",
                        "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com",
                        "spot.amazonaws.com",
                        "spotfleet.amazonaws.com",
                        "transitgateway.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

Here is the module to create ec2 instance.

```
module "ec2" {
  source                       = "terraform-aws-modules/ec2-instance/aws"
  version                      = "4.1.4"

  name                        = var.ec2_name
  ami                         = var.ami
  instance_type               = var.instance_type
  availability_zone           = var.availability_zone
  subnet_id                   = data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.public_subnets[0]
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.WebServerSG.id]
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  key_name                    = var.key_name
  monitoring                  = true

  iam_instance_profile        = aws_iam_instance_profile.jenkins_server.name

  enable_volume_tags          = false
  root_block_device = [
    {
      encrypted   = true
      volume_type = "gp3"
      throughput  = 200
      volume_size = 100
      tags = {
        Name = "jenkins_server"
      }
    },
  ]

  tags = {
    Name = "WebServerSG"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `assume_role_policy` is incorrect. For ec2 instances it [should](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) be:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": { "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"},
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you current `assume_role_policy` should be written in [aws_iam_role_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide more information on top of [the good answer from Marcin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73440908/118587). In AWS IAM roles there are two kinds of policies you might specify (which at first might be confusing):

- assume role policy - i.e. "who"/what can assume this role, as Marcin mentions here you would like to specify that EC2 instances can assume this role - i.e. act in this role
- role policy - i.e. what can this role do; in your case it will be all these elasticloadbalancing, cloudwatch, etc.

So, putting that into Terraform perspective:

- the former should go to `assume_role_policy` of a `aws_iam_role`
- the latter should go to a separate `resource "iam_role_policy"`